# Can Go's linker override initialized variables

Tags: go

From [ld's docs](https://golang.org/cmd/ld/):

> -X symbol value
>
> Set the value of an otherwise uninitialized string variable. The symbol name should be of the form importpath.name, as displayed in the symbol table printed by "go tool nm".

So this is pretty cool. It allows you to do stuff like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var version string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(version)
}
```

Compile with: `go build -ldflags '-X main.version 42' ...`

I have two question about his feature. First of all it also works for initialized strings (e.g. `var version = "bad build"`) even though the documentation specifically says "otherwise *uninitialized* string variable".

The seconds question is about spaces. My `Makefile` contains the following lines:

```
GIT_BRANCH := $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)
GIT_COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD 2>/dev/null)

LDFLAGS := '-X main.version "$(GIT_BRANCH) $(GIT_COMMIT)"'
```

The [documentation for the `go` command](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) says:

> `-ldflags 'flag list'`

So they're using single quotes for all linker flags. But what about a string containing spaces as symbol for the `-X` flag? The double-quotes work just fine, so do escaped single-quotes btw., I'm just not sure I can rely on all that to work consistently given the docs not mentioning any of it.

**Clarification of the first question:**

Go zero-initializes all vars.

The documentation says: `-X symbol value Set the value of an otherwise uninitialized string variable [...]`.

Does this mean:

```
var foo string // only this one?
var bar = "bar" // or this one too, maybe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes are handled by the shell (or make), so yes it's consistent.

The calling program populates `go`'s args.

//edit

To use a default version you can use something like this:

```
var version string

func init() {
    if len(version) == 0 {
        version = "master"
    }
}
```

//edit 2

From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value):

> When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a
>   declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization
>   is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each
>   element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false
>   for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, **"" for strings**, and nil
>   for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. What about the initialized variable though?

Comment: Well... all variables in Go are initialized to their zero value by default. So I have no idea how would you find an uninitialized variable to set.

Comment: @superlukas what exactly do you mean? do you want to use a specific valid if i's not set?

Comment: @OneOfOne again, from the docs `-X symbol value Set the value of an otherwise uninitialized string variable [...]` I know Go zero-initializes all vars. I guess they use the term in a wider sense. (Edited the question as well. See above.)

Comment: @superlukas an uninitialized variable is `var x type` (aka zero-valued), there's also an uninitialized pointer like `var x *type`.